# jquery Have same div show on multiple hovers

Tags: jquery

I have several divs of the same class that I want to show the same div whenever any of them are hovered over. I only want to create this second div once. I have tried creating it within the document and then cloning and appending it whenever I need it. This isn't working. In the example below, I main_item is the class being hovered over and optionbar is the div to show. Note that any main_item class is assigned an id of 9999 when you hover over it and the id is removed when you hover away from it.

```
$(function(){
    $(".main_item").hover(function(){
     $('.optionbar').clone().appendTo("#9999");
    }
    ,function(){
         $("#9999").remove('.optionbar');
    }
);        
});
```

Comment: Tricky to understand what your trying to do here, can you post a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Tried doing it in jsfiddle with no real success. Think of it as having a menu that will display any time you hover over a related item. I don't want to create that menu each time an associated item is created and then show it on hover, I want to dynamically create it and show it and then destroy it when the hover is over.

Comment: 9999 is not a valid id. Your approach is not correct. Follow Trapper's answer. If you want your logic, do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/U5xYS/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You will find working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vqkda/).

Code example:

```
$("div#test").hover(
   function () {
      $(this).append($("<div> ***</div>"));
    }, function () {
       $(this).find("div:last").remove();
    }
);​
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i catched, but you should use `this` for the current element you are hover

```
$(function(){
    $(".main_item").bind('hover',function(){
     $('.optionbar').clone().appendTo(this);
     $(this).remove('.optionbar');

    });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you need to clone it, just move it around and show/hide as needed

```
$(function(){
    $(".main_item").hover(function()
    {
        $('.optionbar').show().appendTo(this);

    }, function()
    {
        $('.optionbar').hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trapper/F94Db/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** ([`Demo Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/ePGgF/))

```
$(".main_item").hover(
   function() {
    $('.optionbar').show().appendTo(this);
}, function() {
    $('.optionbar').hide();
});​
```

Hope this helps!